# How to set values dynamically to a drop down list?

Tags: c#

Let's consider that I have two date fields.

```
DateTime dt1 = "01/04/2012"
DateTime dt2 = "31/08/2012"
```

Here my dates are in "DD/MM/YYYY" format. Here dt1 is the start date and dt2 is the end date. As from the two date fields, I can be able to know that it lies in 04,05,06,07,08 months.

So I want to show on my dropdown list items as combination of month and year.

```
04/2012
05/2012
06/2012
07/2012
08/2012
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Also, a simple search of C# and datetime will give you the answer on how to get the month and year from a datetime object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like below will give you a list of string, that you can use to bind to the drop down.

```
 DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact("01/04/2012", "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact("31/08/2012", "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
List<string> list = new List<string>();
while (dt2 > dt1)
     {
      list.Add(dt1.Month + "/" + dt1.Year);
      dt1 = dt1.AddMonths(1);
      }
```

If you output it using foreach you will get:

```
    foreach (string str in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }


4/2012
5/2012
6/2012
7/2012
8/2012
```

Later if its ASP.Net (because you used dropdownlist), you can do

```
    DropDownList1.DataSource = list;
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Comment: do you really needs to create a List?

Comment: @MMK, No, there are other alternatives as well, its just easy to code, I suppose

Answer (score 0):

```
        DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2012,04,01);
        DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2012,08,30);

        int firstMonth = dt1.Month;
        int lastMonth =dt2.Month;
        //Then you can compare the two numbers as you like
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
int firstMonth = Int32.Parse(dt1.Month);
int secondMonth = Int32.Parse(dt2.Month);
int year = Int32.Parse(dt1.Year);
// You could do some checking if the year is different or something.
for(int month = firstMonth; month <= secondMonth; month++)
    // Add the date to the drop down list by using (month + year).ToString()
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If Asp.net:

```
   DateTime dt1 = new DateTime();
    dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact("01/04/2012", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    DateTime dt2 = new DateTime();
    dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact("31/08/2012", "dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    while (dt2 > dt1)
    {
        dt1 = dt1.AddMonths(1);
        this.dateDropDownList.Items.Add(dt1.ToString("MM / yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
```

if windows form:

```
    DateTime dt1 = new DateTime();
    dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact("01/04/2012", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    DateTime dt2 = new DateTime();
    dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact("31/08/2012", "dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    while (dt2 > dt1)
    {
        dt1 = dt1.AddMonths(1);
        this.dateComboBox.Items.Add(dt1.ToString("MM / yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
```